# How to run one source per task manager (or per node)?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have implemented source which open fixed UDP port and listen it. So, I want to run exactly one source per task manager (in my case I run one task manager per node) because overwise a `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` exception will be thrown.

I notice this problem when test HA of Apache Flink. When I shut down one task manager the Apache Flick started trying to run two sources with the same port on one node.

So, how to run exactly one source per task manager (or per cluster node)?

Comment: Have you tried with setting the parallelism to the number of nodes you have?

Comment: How to do it dynamically (base on number task managers or nodes)?

Comment: From the doc: "The default parallelism can be overwriten for an entire job by calling setParallelism(int parallelism) on the ExecutionEnvironment or by passing -p <parallelism> to the Flink Command-line frontend. It can be overwritten for single transformations by calling setParallelism(int parallelism) on an operator. See the programming guide for more information about the parallelism."

Comment: Sure, I know it. But how to change parallelism dynamically (base on number task managers or nodes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to dynamically enforce that exactly one task of a kind runs on each `TaskManager`. You can avoid that multiple source tasks are scheduled to the same machine by setting the number of slots to `1`. However, then if you lose a machine and don't have a spare `TaskManager`, then you won't have enough slots to restart the job.

Alternatively, you could write your sources such that they are more resilient. For example, you could simple stop a source if they cannot bind to the specified port. Given that no other program can bind to the port, then you know that there is already another source task consuming data from this port.

Comment: I see a problem in first solution: source can be started on any task manager/node but I can send data only to one node (active/master node) of cluster. So, second solution is more interesting but I have a questions:
1) Could you please explain what does it mean "stop source"? How to stop source?
2) As I understand AF will try to restart stoped source. Right? So, in this case AF will be pereodically restart flow. Right?

Comment: Simply leave the `run` function. This will finish the task. So you can try to open a socket and if that fails, then you leave the `run` method.

Comment: Update: I noticied a problem with such solution. It blocks creation of checkpoints: "Checkpoint triggering task Source: RSyslog (2/2) is not being executed at the moment. Aborting checkpoint." Where 'RSyslog (2/2)' source is in FINISHED state.

Comment: This is a shortcoming of the current Flink implementation. In the future, we'll enhance the CheckpointCoordinator such that it can deal with closed/finished operators.